# Xamarin make sure the project is created before archiving error

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I want to archive my application in xamarin, I get the error make sure the project is created before archiving I'm using **Visual Studio 2019**

I wanted to archive the application in visual studio, I was going to create apk, but I got the error make sure the project is created before archiving

Comment: Please provide more details and the actual error message you see (in text form). What exactly did you try? Please also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you provide some more error message or relevant code?